# JavaScript working on IE and Edge but not working on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript

This is working fine on IE and Edge but showing NaN:NaN in Chrome and Firefox. Please provide reason and correct solution for it
I am trying to show only one hour decreasing time.

```
<!--HERE IS MY CODE-->
<!--THE CODE CREATIN ERROR-->
<html>
<head>
<script>
    endtime="31/12/2015";
    var myvar=setInterval(myfunc,1000);//function calling after every 1 second
    var d=new Date();
    d.setHours(14);
    d.setMinutes(00);


    k=00;
    j=01;
    function myfunc()
    {strong text
        d.setSeconds(k);
        k++;
        if(k==60)
        {
            d.setMinutes(j);
            k=00;
            j++;
        }
        var t = parseFloat(Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(d));
        var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
        var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
        var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
        var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=minutes.toString()+":"+seconds.toString();/*HERE IT IS SAYING NAN:NAN IN CHROME AND FIREFOX*/
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [**WHY ARE WE YELLING?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262688/preventing-all-caps-question-titles-and-bodies) Seriously, you'll find questions are much easier to read if you don't capitalise **every** word.

Comment: The line containing `strong text` is not valid in JavaScript. Also, the value of `t` is NaN, so maths with this value will also be NaN

Comment: `Date.parse` is only guaranteed to parse a string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date - other different formats may be supported by different browsers, but there's no guarantees. Obviously IE/Edge support 'dd/mm/yyyy' ("31/12/2015") - other browsers do not - [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) explains it all

Comment: You can check out [this link for count down timer](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp).

Comment: Julian Soro Strong Text is written by mistake , it is not included in actual code

Answer (score 0):

tried to solve a problem from a new approach and done it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

            var t = parseFloat(3600000);

            var myvar=setInterval(myfunc,1000);

            function myfunc()
            {
            if(t>0)
            {
            var seconds = parseFloat(Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 ).toString());
            var minutes = parseFloat(Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 ).toString());
            var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
            var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
            document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=minutes+":"+seconds;

            t=t-1000;
            };}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<div id="div1"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```